# How to provide custom librairy locations with cmake variables (compiling SYSTRAN/fuzzy-match project with cmake)?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation

I never used CMake and C++ before now and I'm trying to compile this project: https://github.com/SYSTRAN/fuzzy-match.
After the installation of the dependencies, I followed the steps in the Compiling section:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Then I have this error with the cmake .. command:

```
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0") found components: serialization iostreams system 
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0") found components: program_options 
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0") found components: filesystem 
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
/home/paul/Documents/proj_tansv/fuzzy-match-master/src/OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_INCLUDE
   used as include directory in directory /home/paul/Documents/proj_tansv/fuzzy-match-master/src
OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_LIB
    linked by target "FuzzyMatch" in directory /home/paul/Documents/proj_tansv/fuzzy-match-master/src

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/paul/Documents/proj_tansv/fuzzy-match-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/paul/Documents/proj_tansv/fuzzy-match-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I know it's because I have to provide custom librairy locations with the cmake variables

```
OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_ROOT for OpenNMT_Tokenize path.
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH for ICU path, prefer this over ICU_ROOT as it will properly use your path over system paths.
BOOST_ROOT for Boost path.
GTEST_ROOT for Google Test path.
```

as said in the github, but I don't know how to do it...
I think I have to edit the CMakeLists.txt file but still I don't know how.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT:

I didn't install OpenNMT/Tokenizer the right way, so I cloned this repository https://github.com/OpenNMT/Tokenizer and followed the instruction in the Compiling section. Now I have this error:

```
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0") found components: serialization iostreams system 
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0") found components: program_options 
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0") found components: filesystem 
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_LIB
    linked by target "FuzzyMatch" in directory /home/paul/Documents/proj_tansv/fuzzy-match-master/src

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/paul/Documents/proj_tansv/fuzzy-match-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/paul/Documents/proj_tansv/fuzzy-match-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

It seems like the problem is linked with the CMakeLists.txt file :

```
 project(FuzzyMatch)                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                              
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                              
 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)                                                                                                                                                                   
 set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                              
 add_compile_options(-pedantic -ansi)                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                              
 if(TARGET OpenNMTTokenizer)                                                                                                                                                                  
   set(OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_LIB OpenNMTTokenizer)                                                                                                                                                
   set(OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_INCLUDE "")  # Resolved via the target.                                                                                                                              
 else()                                                                                                                                                                                       
   find_library(OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_LIB OpenNMTTokenizer REQUIRED HINTS ${OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_ROOT}/lib)                                                                                          
   find_path(OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_INCLUDE onmt/Tokenizer.h REQUIRED HINTS ${OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_ROOT}/include)                                                                                     
 endif()                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                              
 include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                              
 add_subdirectory(src)                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                              
 if (NOT LIB_ONLY)                                                                                                                                                                            
   add_subdirectory(cli)                                                                                                                                                                      
 endif()                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                              
 if (NOT CLI_ONLY AND NOT LIB_ONLY)                                                                                                                                                           
   add_subdirectory(test)                                                                                                                                                                     
 endif()
```

I still don't know how to fix it...

Comment: Variables could be passed using `-D` option for `cmake`. E.g. `cmake -DOPENNMT_TOKENIZER_ROOT=/path/to/tokenizer -DGTEST_ROOT=/path/to/googletest`.

Comment: ok thanks @Tsyvarev, and what the path is supposed to be ? Is it the general path where I put my dependency or a subrepository containing some specific files ?

Comment: In most cases `*_ROOT` variable denotes an **installation prefix**. E.g. if the dependency was built and installed using CMake, then it is what you have specified as `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=...` parameter. Note, that setting of `*_ROOT` variable is normally needed only if you have specified a **custom** installation prefix for your dependency. If you don't specified such prefix, then some default directory is used for installation, and that directory is searched by CMake by default.

Comment: If setting some variable doesn't help, then show your **exact attempt**, and describe how **exactly** have you installed the corresponded dependency.

Comment: ah ok I understand, so I as I didn't specify a custom installation prefix, I guess I don't need to use *_ROOT variable... so the problem seems to concern the CMakeLists.txt file

Comment: ok thanks, I edited my post

Comment: You seems didn't quite understand the request "describe how exactly have you installed the corresponded dependency". Well, lets take another route. The command `find_path(OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_INCLUDE ...)` set variable `OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_INCLUDE` to contain directory, where exists the file `onmt/Tokenizer.h`. Do your installation of OpenNMT Tokenizer contains the file `Tokenizer.h`? (Use any way to search the file.) If it contains the file, then what is **absolute path** of that file? (An absolute path is like `/usr/local/include/onmt/Tokenizer.h`.)

Comment: I'm really sorry, I wasn't very clear, you're right^^ yes Tokenizer.h is present, the absolute path is /home/paul/Tokenizer/include/onmt/Tokenizer.h

Comment: So the path `/home/paul/Tokenizer` seems to be an **installation prefix**. Try to use it as a value for `OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_ROOT` variable.

Comment: yeah I did : ```cmake .. -DOPENNMT_TOKENIZER_ROOT=/home/paul/Tokenizer```
but still I have the error with ```OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_LIB```...

Comment: Do you have files under directory `/home/paul/Tokenizer/lib/`? CMake searches for the one named as `OpenNMTTokenizer` with possible `lib` prefix and `.a` or `.so` extension. Do you have such file?

Comment: Oh you're right ! in fact strangly I don't have any lib directory in Tokenizer...

Comment: I found the file in the build directory

Comment: Is files structure under `/home/paul/Tokenizer` directory resembles the one at the reference: https://github.com/OpenNMT/Tokenizer? If yes, then you have only **sources** for the Tokenizer project and you haven't **install** it as required by fuzzy-match project. (The installation is performed by `make install`).

Comment: Yes I didn't enter ```make install``` in the Tokenizer project, now it's done and after replacing the line 
```find_library(OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_LIB OpenNMTTokenizer REQUIRED HINTS ${OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_ROOT}/lib) ```
by ```find_library(OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_LIB OpenNMTTokenizer REQUIRED HINTS ${OPENNMT_TOKENIZER_ROOT}/build)```
 everything is working perfectly now ! Thanks a lot @Tsyvarev !